# C# Thread async processing

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, task

I have an application which I have chosen to thread.  The intent behind this is to run multiple threads at once to speed up the application.

Currently I loop the application settings, creating a thread for each setting, then start each one, and join so I can tell when they all complete.

unfortunately in doing this, each thread is run synchronously which defeats the purpose.

I could change it to remove the join, but then I cannot determine when all the threads finish (I need to do this as when they are all finished, I have a single process to run).

I am starting to think threading is not for me, but that I should be looking more at the threading.tasks or the parallel.foreach, but I am unsure of the complexities of either of these.  I have not used either mechanism before (and also only dabbled with threads)

below is a code snippet that spawns my threads currently

```
foreach (SettingsProperty value in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
{
    //parse out the line in the settings
    if (value.Name.ToString() != <<criteria>>)
    {
        //this is one that we want to do something with
        sett = value.DefaultValue.ToString().Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);

        //set the directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory(<<directory>>);

        //fire the thread to retrieve the image form the url
        ThreadWithState tws = new ThreadWithState(<<parameters>>);
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(tws.ThreadProc));
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

    }
}
UploadFiles();
```

Currently this executes the threads one by one and then executes the last process.  if I remove the t.join call, this runs the threads async, but also executes the upload before all the threads are complete.

How can I either alter this code to wait for all threads to finish, or 
implement the **Parallel.ForEach** (which I think may work, but have no understanding) or
implement some threading.tasks function so I can use the **Task.WhenAll** method (which I think may also work but have no understanding)

Comment: Why are you calling `t.Join()`?

Comment: Your question is too broad. There are lots of valid ways to run things concurrently. Your code attempts none of those ways. By immediately calling `Join()` on the thread you just started, you don't start another thread until the current one is done. If you don't want to wait before starting another thread, **then don't wait**.

Comment: You say you know what the right tool is -- build an asynchronous workflow -- and that you don't know how to do it.  So *learn how to do it*. This isn't a tutorial site; there are plenty of tutorials on both parallel and asynchronous workflows. Go get one! For IO bound tasks like this, I would start by learning about asynchronous workflows. There's no need to involve multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.Join()` instructs the executing thread to block (wait) until the other thread completes its task.

So this

```
t.Start();
t.Join();
```

literally means start the task and do nothing until it finishes.

If you want to use `Parallel.ForEach` you could start by creating the list of whatever it is you want to operate on. For example,

```
var properties = Properties.Settings.Default.Properties
    .Where(property => Name != "whatever");
```

Now `properties` is an `IEnumerable<SettingsProperty>` - a collection that can be enumerated, or looped through.

Now you can do this:

```
Parallel.ForEach(properties, (property) =>
    {
        // do something with the property.
    });
```

This is essentially the same as

```
foreach(var property in properties)
{
    // do something with the property.
}
```

except that the iterations of the loop *may* run on concurrent threads. "May" because the task scheduler uses threads according to the workload and what's available.